# Removing attribute set along with extension removal

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, extensions, product-attribute

I have a custom Magento extension which is adding a new attribute to `catalog product`, but with one big problem. If you want to delete it (*the extension*), on the product page and the admin product page there will be a fatal error, because in the database a reference to the frontend model and backend model still exist.

I need to find the event which is responsible for removing a Magento package extension, and then also delete the attribute set in it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Magento does not support uninstall scripts. You will have to delete the attribute manually.

Comment: Do you know why they don't allow it?

Comment: @ladle3000. I have no idea..there is some code in the core that should handle an uninstall script but is never used.

Comment: It's a shame, so much additional stress as store owners sift through uninstall instructions to see how to unbreak their website.  Thats after they figure to reference uninstall instructions.

Comment: Magento supports it, you only need to implement it yourself. But if you delete the code the uninstallscript will be gone too.